# Lock web page in Django admin if another user in that page

Tags: html, django, locking, admin

I'm new to Django.

I'm looking for a way to lock a custom template in the Django admin for accessing more than 1 user at a time. Is there a way to do it with Sessions? Or do it with javascript?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't believe there is a built-in solution that comes prepackaged, with Django, you should take a look at the [django-admin-page-lock](https://pypi.org/project/django-admin-page-lock/) package as I think it does what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I already took a look, but can't figure out how to make it work. Gonna give it another try!